# MongoRegex and search multiple rows in collection

Tags: php, json, mongodb, search

What I would like to do is the following.

```
$collection = $this->db->products_sale;

        $user_query = preg_replace("/[[:blank:]]+/"," ", $data);
        $arr_query = explode(' ', $user_query);

        if (count($arr_query) > 1) {
        $tmp = array();

        foreach ($arr_query as $q) {
            $tmp[] = new MongoRegex( "/". $q ."/i" );
        }

        $who['keywords'] = array('$in' => $tmp);
        $who['title'] = array('$in' => $tmp);
        $who['description'] = array('$in' => $tmp);

        } else {
            $who['keywords'] = new MongoRegex( "/". $user_query ."/" );
            $who['title'] = new MongoRegex( "/". $user_query ."/" );
            $who['description'] = new MongoRegex( "/". $user_query ."/" );
        }

        print json_encode($who);
        $cursor = $collection->find( $who );
```

As you can see I am doing a number of searches, what I would like to do, is the following I need to be able to search keywords, title, description

Now I could do a number of searches which is what I thought I was doing, but clearly not. from what I got, it seems it sends one long string ARRAY or JSON back to the mongoDB, unlike MySQL where you can do a OR/AND search and even a MATCH search it seems MongoDB just not that smart.

This is what I found works, but then it searches for the exact way the search searches for e.g

"windows phone 7" would get searched instead of keywords.

```
$cursor = $collection->find( 
        array('$or' => array(
        array("keywords" => new MongoRegex( "/$user_query/i" )),
        array("product" => new MongoRegex( "/$user_query/i" )),
        array("description" => new MongoRegex( "/$user_query/i" )),
        )));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that wants to know how I ended up getting it to work. It was quite simple. I am still working on it, but here is what I have so far.

```
$collection = $this->db->products_sale;

    $user_query = preg_replace("/[[:blank:]]+/"," ", $data);
    $arr_query = explode(' ', $user_query);

    if (count($arr_query) > 1) {
    $tmp = array();

    foreach ($arr_query as $q) {
        $tmp[] = new MongoRegex( "/". $q ."/i" );
    }

    $who['keywords'] = array('$in' => $tmp);
    $who['product'] = array('$in' => $tmp);

    } else {
        $who['keywords'] = new MongoRegex( "/". $user_query ."/" );
        $who['product'] = new MongoRegex( "/". $user_query ."/" );
    }

    //print json_encode($who);
    $cursor = $collection->find( 
    array('$or' => array($who
    )));


    if ($cursor->count() > 0)
    {
    //print "found you";
    $test = array();
    // iterate through the results
    while( $cursor->hasNext() ) {   
        $test[] = ($cursor->getNext());
    }
    print json_encode($test);
```

Comment: Depending on how much data you plan to add, I suspect performance will quickly become an issue.  The multiple (and non-anchored) regular expressions will not use an index. See the [notes on Regular Expressions](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions).  A better approach would be to index your documents using a [Full Text Search approach](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Full+Text+Search+in+Mongo) against a list of extracted keywords or to use a Full Text Search Engine which would provide richer search features and relevancy scoring.