# search in combination two field in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I use from Mongodb and my database schema like this:

```
firstName: 'vahid',
lastName: 'kh',
age: 12
```

I want find all records that firstname + lastname likes 'vahid kh'. In SQL, this would be:

> Select * from table where firstName + lastName like '%vahid kh%'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems this is available only in 2.4, which was released today.

```
> db.temp.save({ "firstName" : "Bob", "lastName" : "Smith", Age : 12 });
> db.temp.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5148a2a00477cddcdece1b34"), "firstName" : "Bob", "lastName" : "Smith", "Age" : 12 }
> db.temp.aggregate({ $project : { "name" : { $concat : [ "$firstName", " ", "$lastName" ] } } });
{
    "result" : [
       {
           "_id" : ObjectId("5148a2a00477cddcdece1b34"),
           "name" : "Bob Smith"
       }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: This doesn't search for anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$regex`, this way you can use partial matches.
Something like that:

```
db.collection.find( { field: /acme.*corp/i } )
```

Here is somewhat similar question with answer in php: [MongoRegex and search multiple rows in collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281671/mongoregex-and-search-multiple-rows-in-collection)

Docs about mongoregex are here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/

**Edit:**

I just read your comment with query in sql. Simple solution could be to make field `fullname` and search it with `$regex`, it is kind of db denormalization, where you store somewhat redundant data.

Or even easier, this should do the job too:

```
db.collection.find( { firstName: /*vahid/i, lastName: /kh*/i } )
```

Comment: This tries to answer the very particular case in the OP's question, but the general case answer is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495368/search-in-combination-two-field-in-mongodb/56299944#56299944).

Answer (score 1):

To search against a combination of two or more fields, you need to use the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/). It lets you sort by the combinations of fields, and you don't need to store (denormalize) any extra fields:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        // Optional criteria to select only some documents to process, such as...
        deleted: null
    }
},
{
    $addFields: {
        // Need to prefix fields with '$'
        fullName: { $concat: [ "$firstName", "$lastName" ] },
    }
},
{
    $search: { fullName: /.*vakid kh.*/ },
}
]);
```

Explanation:

- the [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) aggregation pipeline stage creates dynamic, on-the-fly fields
- [$concat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/) creates the `fullName` field by concatenating the first and last name
- `$search` does a [regular expression search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/), which is the MongoDB equivalent to the SQL `LIKE` operator.

Answer (score 0):

I have code in expressjs  code aggregate is bit slow then find so I have use conditional based and use regular express to find true results, I am sharing with you nodejs code I hope it useful for you or my other code lover friends.

```
router.get('/publisher/:q',function(req,res){

  var q = ucfirst( req.params['q'] );
  var qSplit = q.split(" ");
  var db = mongojs(CONNECTION_STRING, ['tags_helper','users']);
  var query = { "status" : 1, isAdmin : { $exists : false } };

  console.log(qSplit);

  if( qSplit.length > 1  )
  {

    query["firstName"] = new RegExp(qSplit[0],"i");
    query["lastName"] =  new RegExp(qSplit[1],"i");

  }
  else
  {
    qSplit[0] = new RegExp(qSplit[0],"i");
    qSplit[1] = new RegExp(qSplit[0],"i"); 

    //query.push( { $or : [  {"firstName": new RegExp(q,"i")},{"lastName": new RegExp(q,"i")} ]  } );
    query["$or"] = [  {"firstName": new RegExp(q,"i")},{"lastName": new RegExp(q,"i")} ];
  }

  db.users.find( query,{_id : 1,firstName:1,lastName:1,image:1,profileName:1}).limit(10,function (err, users) {

    //TODO your further code .. 


  });
});
```

Have a happy coding day.

Comment: Express is completely irrelevant.